# Как парсить Map (JSON) в Angular?

Tags: html, json, typescript, angular, map

Есть фронт на Angular который отправляет запрос:

```
{"method":"limit_objects","id":"req-id-01","jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

и получает ответ:

```
{"result":{"object_1":"10000","object_2":"20000","object_3":"15000","object_4":"15000"},"id":"req-id-01","jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

Вот код который это выполнят на фронте:

```
class Limit {
  id: any;
  limitMap: Map<string, string>;
  constructor(id: any, result: Map<string, string>) {
    this.id = id;
    this.limitMap = result;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  url = 'http://dc1-kafka-utils01.awis.np.ua:9098/rpc';
  response: any;
  limits: Limit;
  title: string;
  loggedIn = true;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

  getLimits() {
    this.response = this.http.post(this.url, '{"method":"limit_objects","id":"req-id-01","jsonrpc":"2.0"}')
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.response = response;
        this.limits = (response as Limit);
        console.log(this.limits.id);
      });
  }
}
```

попытка вывести в браузер:

```
<button (click)="getLimits()">Button</button>

<p *ngFor="let item of limits.limitMap">
    {{item}}
</p>
```

но получаю ошибку `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'limitMap' of undefined`

Собственно вопрос, как правильно распарсить весь JSON response, и в частности Map (поле result в JSON)?

Comment: это не валидный json

Comment: Почему не валидный, что в нем не так?  JSON RPC 2.0

Comment: пропущена открывающая фигурная скобка после первого двоеточия, проверьте онлайн валидатором

Comment: это при вставке текста в форму глюкнуло, поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Ты сделал все правильно. Возможно дело в том, что на момент построения списка, объект еще не готов, ведь запрос асинхронный, так еще и заполняется по клику.

Чтобы ошибка не появлялась, попробуй после `limits` в разметке указать вопросительный знак: `limits?.limitMap`.

Comment: а что значит знак вопроса? где можно почитать не подскажите?

Comment: В Angular и Typescript это называется optional chaining. Это означает, что поле может отсутствовать или браться от null/undefined. Если это так, то вернется undefined, иначе искомое значение.